# Why JS Error IN IE6 (not var variables)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I coded the following JS

```
<html>
 <body>
   <img id="img" src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
(function(){
    img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = "http://example.com/img.png";
})();
  //]]>
</script> 
 </body>
```

but on IE6
some js errors are occured.

Because Should I use var img?
incidentally

```
     <body>
       <img id="img" src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        img.src = "http://example.com/img.png";
    })();
      //]]>
    </script> 
     </body>

</html>
```

is no problem
I can't get the reason why
Could you explain me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you omit `var` when you're declaring a variable, and that variable doesn't exist in current local scope, one of two things will happen:

1. you'll declare a new "global" variable, to which every function will have access to -> don't do this
2. you'll set an already existing global variable to a new value; if some other function relies on this variable, you could wreak havoc

So, don't use global variables and use `var` whenever possible. As Tomas already pointed out, your script could be run before the structure is loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The script is running before the whole body structure is loaded by the browser. So, your function can't find the `img` element.
Invoking your function at the `onLoad` body event would fix the error.

I.e:

```
<html>
 <head>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     //<![CDATA[
    function loadImage(){
      img = document.getElementById("img");
      img.src = "http://example.com/img.png";
      }
  //]]>
  </script>     

 </head>
 <body onLoad="loadImage();">
   <img id="img" src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for replying! realy? but var term add then this script is no problem

Comment: you code is great! but could I have any other solutions not using onload , because onload have already set another function

Comment: No, this is absolutely not the problem. The problem is the collision with `img` caused by not using `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you're not using `var` to declare the `img` variable. There is no problem with the fact that the rest of the body may not have been parsed, so don't worry about that.

The reason that the absence of `var` is causing a problem here is that `img` is colliding with property of the global object created for you by the browser. In IE, each element with an ID creates a property of the global object (which is therefore accessible everywhere) corresponding to that ID. This property is read-only, so if you try and assign to it, you get an error. If you declare it first, you create a new variable which doesn't interfere with IE's global property and it will work as you expect.

You would also find that changing the variable name not to collide with an ID or property of `window` would fix the problem:

```
banana = document.getElementById("img");
banana.src = "http://example.com/img.png";
```

... but this is not a good idea either since you're automatically polluting the global scope with your `banana`, which could have consequences in other code, and in ECMAScript 5 strict mode you would get an error.

Finally, unless you're using XHTML (which you almost certainly shouldn't be and your example doesn't have an XHTML doctype), there's no need for the CDATA mark-up. You should remove it.

Moral of the story: **always declare your variables**.